# xcrun doesn't embed provisioning profile into ipa

Tags: xcode, code-signing, ipa, codesign, xcrun

I am writing a build script for my phonegap-ios program. I am experiencing some problems during the code signing process. I use my script to build and code signing the project and generate ipa file. But the ipa failed to install to my iphone via iTunes. And I compared the ipa file which generated by my build script and the ipa file generated from Xcode organizer. The build script doesn't contain embedded.mobileprovision and resourceRules.plist. So anyone can tell me anything wrong with my build script? I have made sure paths are right. I use Xcode 4.6.3 (4H1503) and my Mac OS is 10.8.4. My build script is listed below. Thanks.

`xcodebuild -project $PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj -arch i386 -target $PROJECT_NAME -configuration Release -sdk $SDK clean build VALID_ARCHS="i386" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="$PROJECT_PATH/build"`

`codesign -f -v -s "$CODE_SIGN" "$PROJECT_PATH/$APP"`

`xcrun -log -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "$PROJECT_PATH/$APP" -o "$PROJECT_PATH/build/$PROJECT_NAME.ipa" --embed "$PROFILE"`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while trying to automate my build of iOS app. Apparently `xcrun` in order to embed provisioning profile, requires an **--sign "iPhone Distribution: ..."** option to be specified on command line.